# no module named tensorflow in jupyter noteboook

Tags: tensorflow, jupyter, importerror

I've already tried the following:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I am also facing the same problem. Tensorflow is available in console but not available in jupyter notebook.

Comment: I've solved this problem, in fact. Now, I'll give my answer, see follow.